# How to pass one or other list into a function

Tags: c#, function, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I wondering if someone may be able to help me, I have two `List T` in C#, They are the same apart from one holds customers and one holds vendors. I am trying to pass each one of these lists into a function with no success to avoid having extra code.

Lists created below:

```
var customers = IntuitServiceConfig.ServiceManager.FindAll<Customer>(new Customer(), 1, 500);
var vendor = IntuitServiceConfig.ServiceManager.FindAll<Vendor>(new Vendor(), 1, 500);
```

I would like to pass into the function below:

```
public static string Contacts(AppContext ctx, List<Type1> list )
{
   foreach (var contact in list)
   {
    // do some db work
   }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the two lists aren't the same at all -- they hold fundamentally different objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want/can use same code for both classes(`Customer`, `Vendor`), then change your `Contacts` function to generic

```
public static string Contacts<TContact>(AppContext ctx, List<TContact> list )
{
    foreach (var contact in list)
    {
        // do some db work
    }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = IntuitServiceConfig.ServiceManager.FindAll(new Customer(), 1, 500).ToList();
List<Vendor> vendors = IntuitServiceConfig.ServiceManager.FindAll(new Vendor(), 1, 500).ToList();

String cust = Contacts<Customer>(ctx, customers);
String vend = Contacts<Vendor>(ctx, vendors);
```

**UPDATE**
If your `Vendor` and `Customer` classes are different, not derived from same base class or haven't implemented same interface, than you need write own function for every class

```
public static string Contacts(AppContext ctx, List<Customer> list )
{
    foreach (var contact in list)
    {
        // do some db work with customers
    }
}

public static string Contacts(AppContext ctx, List<Vendor> list )
{
    foreach (var contact in list)
    {
        // do some db work with vendors
    }
}
```

And using:

```
String cust = Contacts(ctx, customers);
String vend = Contacts(ctx, vendors);
```

Comment: Error 1 'TContact' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'TContact' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JimboJones, show your code how you call `Contact<TContact>` function. I updated answer with overloading same function for different types. On the other hand @Andrew Cooper answer seems better approaching if you want keep all in same function

Answer (score 2):

You could try making the method generic:

```
public static string Contacts<TElement>(AppContext ctx, List<TElement> list )
{
  foreach (TElement element in list)
  {
    // do some db work
  }
}
```

**Update**

You need to have both object implement the same interface (or, alternately, derive from the same base class).  You could create an `IContact` interface like this:

```
interface IContact 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    // other common properites
}
```

... modify the contact classes like this:

```
class Customer : IContact
{
    // rest of Customer definition
}

class Vendor : IContact
{
    // rest of Vendor definition
}
```

... and then change the method like this:

```
public static string Contacts<TContact>(AppContext ctx, List<TContact> list )
    where TContact : IContact
{
  foreach (TContact element in list)
  {
    // do some db work
  }
}
```

... or just:

```
public static string Contacts(AppContext ctx, List<IContact> list )
{
  foreach (IContact element in list)
  {
    // do some db work
  }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'TElement' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'TElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  string ContactId = element.Id.ToString();

Comment: @JimboJones - You'll need to define an interface that specifies the common operations that you want to perform on the list elements.  Either that or have `Customer` and `Vendor` derive from the same base class.  You can then add a type specifier to the method.

Answer (score 0):

If `Customer` and `Vendor` both inherit from the same base class, and you don't actually need to change the lists themselves in the function, than try using `IEnumerable` in your function's signature

```
public static string Contacts(AppContext ctx, IEnumerable<BaseClass> list )
```